# File in resources folder is not found

Tags: java

I have a file located in `src\main\resources\templates\attendee_registration.html`

I tried to load the file with freemarker using this code:

```
    @Autowired
    private Configuration freemarkerConfig;

    private String geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(Map<String, Object> model){

        freemarkerConfig.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/templates/");

        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        try{
         content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString( 
                 freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("attendee_registration.html"), model));
         return content.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception occured while processing fmtemplate:"+e.getMessage());
        }
          return "";
    }
```

But I get:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at deployment.platform.war//com.web.registration.Register.geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(Register.java:132)`

at this line:

`freemarkerConfig.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/templates/");`

This is a JSF application deployed into Wildfly server. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107179/autowiring-of-freemarker-configuration-fails